# Using MikTex, adding bibliography, getting a "Undefined Control Sequence"

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, miktex

I'm using MikTex v2.9 for homework in the subject computergraphics at university.

I'm using the acmsiggraph layout.

```
\documentclass[tog]{acmsiggraph}
```

So my problem is, I'm trying to use BibTex for my bibliography and everytime I get an error while compiling:

```
(C:\Users\Khaled\Desktop\CGI_Mitschrift\CG1_Mitschrift\Mitschrift.bbl
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@listctr 

l.3 \bibitem{rehfeld}
```

My BBL-File looks weird, year and published are missing. I don't know why.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{rehfeld}
Stephan Rehfeld.
\newblock Digitale bilder.

\end{thebibliography}
```

My Bibfile named "bib.bib" looks like this:

```
    @misc{rehfeld,
    AUTHOR      = "Stephan Rehfeld",
    TITLE           = {"Digitale Bilder"},
    HOWPUBLISHED    = "\url{https://public.beuth-hochschule.de/~rehfeld/lehre/2015/ss/digitale-bilder.pdf}",
    YEAR            = "2015"
}
```

I added the bibfile at the end of the document like I'm supposed to do.

```
\bibliographystyle{acmsiggraph}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

The weird thing is, if I ignore the error, the "Literatur"-Section in my PDF looks OK, and has all the information from the .bib-file in it. And the bbl-file looks OK too and has all the information in it:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{rehfeld}
Stephan Rehfeld.
\newblock Digitale bilder.
\newblock
 https://public.beuth-hochschule.de/~rehfeld/lehre/2015/ss/digitale-bilder.pdf,
 2015.

\end{thebibliography}
```

But the error stays. So please, if you have any idea help me please. :)

EDIT: Still getting the Error, but it now looks like I can work with it...
And it doesn't matter what I refer to in \cite it shows [0] at any place? :D

[image: Literatur]

Thank you very much!

Comment: When giving the name of the bibliography database, omit the file ending.

Comment: hey, thank you. :) But the error still occurs... :(

If I ignore the error and just go in, it kind of works... :/ Weirdest thing ever... :D

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/johannesbottcher/HinweiseLitverzeichnisse/blob/master/Hinweise.md

Answer (score 1):

The `acmsiggraph` document class file and auxiliary files don't seem to be on the CTAN; however, I found some files at http://www.siggraph.org/sites/default/files/acmsiggraph2015.zip. If that's not where you got the template and document class files from, please state your preferred source for these files.

The main thing to note is that the argument of the `\bibliography` instruction -- the `.bib` file(s) -- should be stated *without the `.bib` extension*. In the present case, that should be

```
\bibliography{bib}
```

With this change in place, you should no longer experience bibtex-related problems. Note that you should encase the `title` field in an additional pair of curly braces, to keep the word "Bilder" from being lower-cased. You may also want to consider using the `acmsiggraph` bibliography style instead of the `plain` bib style.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybibliography.bib}
@misc{rehfeld,
    AUTHOR      = "Stephan Rehfeld",
    TITLE           = "{Digitale Bilder}",
    HOWPUBLISHED    = "\url{https://public.beuth-hochschule.de/~rehfeld/lehre/2015/ss/digitale-bilder.pdf}",
    YEAR            = "2015"
}   
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[tog]{acmsiggraph}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{acmsiggraph}  % not "plain.bst"
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybibliography}  % <-- no ".bib" extension
\end{document}
```

Comment: First of all a massive thank you for your help. And second, the \RequirePackage{filecontents} should be in the .bib file refering at itself? :)

Comment: @Khaled Should be above the line, but be careful. It will overwrite your file!

Comment: @Khaled - The example solution uses the `filecontents` package to make the example self-contained. In general, you should keep your bib file (or bib files) separate from the tex file(s).  I'm renaming the bib file in the solution to reduce the chance of the code overwriting a real file called `bib.bib`.

Comment: Hi there I now changed everything, except the \RequirePackage and it works, but just a little, see my Edit in the post. :/ Maybe you have another clue? :)

Comment: @Mico Hi mico, it now looks very good, but everytime i use \cite it refers to [0] see screenshot, what is this about? By the way still getting the error, but it looks good. :D